# A Cryptic Combination

Tags: story, cryptic-clues

My friend couldn't make it to school today, but wanted me to grab his backpack from his locker for him. He told me he had a combination lock, and sent the following message, saying "There's one clue that has punctuation that I didn't include, but you should be able to figure it out!"

> Under net, counter and employ longest leg (10)
> Sports captains often realize even beginners get points (5)
> Oddly swindled by façade (4)
> Number of bakers sleep before noon? (5)
> Mess up plants without energy of Motown singer (7)
> Fantastic comic publisher associated with British universities (9)
> Poor chance: I am large and robotic! (10)
> Gallery shows inspiration against hesitation (6)
> Nearly cooked salmon with bit of thyme instead of pinch of nutmeg (6)
> Endlessly want class (4)
> Showing love, romantics are a thing of the past (4)
> Quiet minister promises to last (8)

What's the three-number combination? The lock only goes up to 39.

Comment: Since the answer is a combination to a lock, I'm not sure if the [locks] tag applies. Also not sure if the [enigmatic-puzzle] tag applies for the process of actually figuring out the combination, but I think it's too straightforward for the tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the combination is

> 16-13-28.

```
Under net, counter and employ longest leg (10)
```

> HYPOTENUSE (HYPO + NET< + USE)

```
Sports captains often realize even beginners get points (5)
```

> SCORE (initial letters)

```
Oddly swindled by façade (4)
```

> SIDE (odd-numbered letters of SWINDLED)

```
Number of bakers sleep before noon? (5)
```

> DOZEN (DOZE N)

```
Mess up plants without energy of Motown singer (7)
```

> MARVIN'S (MAR VIN(-e)S; Marvin Gaye); this is the punctuated one mentioned in the preamble.

```
Fantastic comic publisher associated with British universities (9)
```

> MARVELOUS (MARVEL + OUS, presumably referring to the Open University or maybe Oxford University)

```
Poor chance: I am large and robotic! (10)
```

> MECHANICAL ((CHANCE I AM L)*)

```
Gallery shows inspiration against hesitation (6)
```

> MUSEUM (MUSE UM)

```
Nearly cooked salmon with bit of thyme instead of pinch of nutmeg (6)
```

> ALMOST ((SALMON with T instead of N)*)

```
Endlessly want class (4)
```

> YEAR (YEAR(-n))

```
Showing love, romantics are a thing of the past (4)
```

> OVER (substring)

```
Quiet minister promises to last (8)
```

> PREVIOUS (P REV IOUS)

That is:

> **hypotenuse score side dozen marvin's marvelous mechanical museum almost year over previous**.

Here,

> "Hypotenuse score side dozen" seems like it might be describing a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse of length 20 and one side of length 12; the other side is then also of integer length, namely 16. Maybe the combination is some permutation of 20-16-12? But we still have the other answers to consider.

After a nudge from OP in comments,

> it looks to me as if successive groups of four clues yield the three numbers. If the four mentioned above yield just *one* number then I suppose it has to be the third side: 16. MMMM must refer not to the (rather obscure) museum of that name in Michigan, but to the album named after it, from the (rather obscure) band Tally Hall. This has a track called "13" so that's probably the next number. Finally we have "almost year over previous"; I guess "almost year" means 364 and "previous" means the number we just found, so 364/13 which equals 28.

Comment: All your clues look good, and to hopefully point you in the right direction rot13(gur svefg sbhe pyhrf (qrfpevovat gur evtug gevnatyr) tvir lbh gur svefg ahzore va gur pbzovangvba).